# Asyncio tasks stopping on await

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

i have one async funcion that got few awaits in it

```
async def registerit(arg1,arg2):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        url="https://google.com"
        headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
        response = await session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

code is stopping on await stuff for some reason it only happends if i use

```
task = asyncio.create_task(registerit(arg1,arg2))
tasks.append(task)
```

function works normal if i use

```
await registerit(arg1,arg0)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the details of how you are really running the code, but I'd guess you're not giving the task you create (with `asyncio.create_task`) its turn for execution.

`await registerit(arg1,arg0)` works, because when you use `await` you switch the current execution context to another coroutine, which might just turn out to be the one that you've just initiated with `await`. Await creates that new coroutine AND waits for it to finish and get its output.

Unlike `await`, tasks are for concurrent (background) work. Remember that when you create it, you just put it on the queue of coroutines to execute at a context switch point. So if **you run `create_task` as the last line of code** the coroutine with the work will be created, and put on the execution queue, but the queue will just stop there with the program.

But if you would yield control of the program back to the event loop with an `await` and **halt the program's end with something like `await asyncio.sleep(5)`** you would **get the "non-working" code running**. Or you could just run your loop with `run_forever()` in the first place.

You can see that by running my test.py:

```py
# test.py
# python 3.8.1

import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def non_working_solution():
    task = asyncio.create_task(registerit())


async def working_solution():
    await registerit()


async def registerit():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        url="https://google.com"
        headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
        response = await session.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(response)


async def main():
    print('Running working solution')
    await working_solution()
    print('Running NON-working solution')
    await non_working_solution()

    # THE FIX
    # =======
    time_to_sleep = 5
    print('Waiting for', time_to_sleep, 'seconds for the output of the non-working solution')
    await asyncio.sleep(time_to_sleep)
    # =======


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```